# How to fill a closed parametric curve?

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a curve in parametric form:

```
ParametricPlot[{(1 - Cos[2 \[Pi] s]) Sin[2 \[Pi] s], 
  Cos[2 \[Pi] s] (Sin[2 \[Pi] s] + 1)}, {s, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> Black]
```

This gives:

[image]

Is there a way to fill it with black?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can post-process `ParametricPlot` output to change `Line` to `FilledCurve`:

```
ParametricPlot[{(1 - Cos[2 π s]) Sin[2 π s], 
   Cos[2 π s] (Sin[2 π s] + 1)}, {s, 0, 1}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Black] /. l_Line :> FilledCurve[l]
```

[image]

Use the replacement rule

```
l_Line :> {Opacity[1.], FilledCurve[l]}
```

to get

[image]

We get the same result if we use a rule that replaces `Line`s with `Polygon`s:

```
Line[x_] :> {Opacity[1], Polygon[Append[x, First @ x]]}
```